# C Two-Way Pipe Not Working

Tags: c, pipe

I am trying to set up a two-way pipe between a parent and child process in C, but my code (as follows) is not working:

```
int main() {
    int fd1[2], fd2[2];
    char c;
    fprintf(stderr, "Pipe 1 return: %i\n", pipe(fd1));
    fprintf(stderr, "Pipe 2 return: %i\n", pipe(fd2));
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error forking");
        return -1;
    }
    if (!pid) {
        dup2(fd1[1], 1);
        dup2(fd2[0], 0);
        close(fd1[0]);
        close(fd2[1]);
        //fprintf(stderr, "setvbuffer output: %i\n", setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0));
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent runing. Receiving\n");
        c = getchar();
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent received char. Modifying\n");
        putchar(c + 2);
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent sent char\n");
    } else {
        dup2(fd1[0], 0);
        dup2(fd2[1], 1);
        close(fd1[1]);
        close(fd2[0]);
        //fprintf(stderr, "setvbuffer output: %i\n", setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0));
        fprintf(stderr, "Child running. Printing\n");
        putchar('c');
        c = getchar();
        fprintf(stderr, "Child received returned char: %c\n", c);
    }

}
```

When I run this the program is immediately left waiting at the first getchar(). I have also tried sending/receiving lines of text, using the commented out setvbuf() lines, using sleep() before reading from stdin, etc.

This is a simplified version of my actual code which is communicating between two different programs, and there I seem to be able to communicate successfully in one direction.

Comment: Stdio buffers output to pipes by default. Use `setbuf()` to turn off the buffering.

Comment: For clarity and precision, there is no such thing as a two-way pipe.  Pipes are inherently unidirectional.  But you can achieve bidirectional communication via pipes by using a separate one for each direction, and this indeed appears to be what you're trying to do.

Comment: As far as your actual problem goes, an alternative to turning off buffering would be to `fflush()` your output streams after writing to them.

Comment: Note also that after the two dup2's you have 4 open file descriptors to close.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by John in the comments, calling fflush(stdout) after each print statement fixes the issue.